Connecting a domain to a VPS
I'm having trouble connecting a domain to my VPS. Maybe I will describe step by step what I did and someone will be able to give me an answer. I bought a VPS on ovhcloud. I installed Ubuntu on it. Later I installed the LAMP and wordpress package. My website works very well via the IP address of the VPS. Let's go to the domain that I also bought via ovhcloud. In the DNS records, I set type A to the ipv4 of my VPS. The AAAA record shows ipv6 of my VPS. I've already waited 2 days. By pinging mydomain.com, it receives a response from the server. The nslookup website also shows the correct IP addresses when I search for mydomain.com. Thats why i am surprised why when I enter mydomain.com in my web browser I receive the response "This website is unreachable".
What is blocking access? Is it somewhere at the VPS or Ubuntu settings level? I will add that I did not make any changes to the domain on the Ubuntu server. I don't really know if anything should be done there.
I'm counting on help from advanced users. Regards

Have you added a CNAME record?

No. I didn't do anything to the CNAME

NO. I didn't do anything to the CNAME. Yesterday I tried to solve the problem using chatgpt. It turned out that I needed to create an Apache configuration file for my domain. The website even started working well. Another problem occurred because the website was not secured. It only worked on http. I used free SSL gateway from ovhcloud. So I redirected the A and AAAA records to this gateway. And then more errors came. Because WordPress via https did not load completely. I only saw subtitles without any graphics. I tried to solve this problem using chatgpt until it stopped working completely... I reinstalled the VPS. And I connected the domain via A and AAAA back to the VPS. I have to think about how to solve this problem.
Edit.
I used certbot yesterday and configured SSL for VPS step by step from the guide. Today I checked that after entering mydomain.com, an Apache secured website with https was displayed. It looks like one problem has been solved. The only question is whether if I install WordPress now, I won't have to change something in the Apache configuration file again.
